# Using ESLINT with OpenUI5 in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint, sapui5, eslint

I am new to OpenUI5 and ESLINT. Since I am using a Javascript view in OpenUI5, I want my code to be following best standards, so I will use ESLINT for that. I couldn't find a way to integrate the ESLINT plugin into Eclipse keeper version to develop an application. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Sorry I'm not really familiar with Eclipse, but try this link: https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter-ESLint

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know you have to use Eclipse Orion (thats the webversion of Eclipse)(SAP WebIDE is a Orion) or use the commandline tool installed via Node.JS.

I am using Atom editor, there you have a Plugin.